# jQuery Sliding Content DIV - slide from right not from top

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate, slidetoggle

I've been asked to create a plugin similar to [this one](http://web-kreation.com/demos/Sliding_login_panel_jquery/#) for a project at work except instead of sliding from the top it should slide in from the right of the page.

I've put a JSFiddle together of my code for something sliding down from the top which is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/xtMCh/2/).

My approach to get the desired effect was to change the style for the divs from `{top:0}` to `{right:0}` and then I swapped all my height and width styles.  I then changed the `slideToggle()` call to be an `animate({width: 'toggle'})` call.  However, as you can see from the next JSFiddle, it really hasn't worked!.  [Here's a JSFiddle of my attempt](http://jsfiddle.net/vVSJz/6/).

Any idea where I'm going wrong?

I found a great example from an old colleague of mine ([@sohnee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/75525/sohnee) on here...) which slides in from the right and I tried copying the relevant styles from his plugin but it didn't make a difference.  As an example, his plugin can be [found here](http://www.stevefenton.co.uk/cmsfiles/assets/File/sidecontent.html).

Cheers,

James

Comment: Adding floats to tab and content seems to work but the tab sometimes jumps under the content. Maybe you could work from this? http://jsfiddle.net/tricki/vVSJz/4/
BTW: you forgot to include jquery in your fiddle

Comment: Cheers guys, I've included the jquery library now.

Comment: @Thomas - that's pretty much what I was looking for but without the space.  I'll see if I can get rid of the space...

Comment: Cool - @Thomas if you stick that as an answer I'll choose it as correct.  There was a white space because I had the tab div width set at 90% in my original js fiddle.  Here's the complete one: http://jsfiddle.net/vVSJz/10/

Comment: to anyone else - here's the full example of what I was going for: http://jsfiddle.net/vVSJz/13/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding floats to tab and content seems to work but the tab sometimes jumps under the content. Maybe you could work from this? [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tricki/vVSJz/4)

Comment: This fiddle is perfect. But I want the button to be fixed even when the body scrolls. I gave position:fixed to panel-tab but it disappears. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Hi James take look at [Slide Elements in Different Directions](http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/02/slide-elements-in-different-directions) probably it can help

I went and check "JSFiddle" sample code that you run... if you choose jQuery framework in JSFiddle to run it works.

Hi again check it now:
[Right Slide Panel](http://jsfiddle.net/MSYfH/)

Comment: I've included the jquery library now.  It still isn't the desired effect as the click should sit next to the sliding content div as the div slides out from the right (hope that makes sense).  Cheers for the link, I'll check it out.